# Load website and fill form from the command line

Tags: shell, automation, webforms

Using the Linux command line (Bash shell) I like to load a specific website in my browser (normally Firefox, but other one would be ok as well as long it runs under Linux) and fill a pre-defined form with some data. Actually, this should run from a Makefile. Most of the form data is static and will be stored as variables in the Makefile, just some fields are to be filled manually before manually sending the form.

I know how to load the [website in question](http://dante.ctan.org/upload.html) from the command line using:

```
firefox <URL>
```

But there seems no possibility to fill the form automatically with variables given on the command line. Is there a plugin, executable or JavaScript which allows me to do this? Any suggestions and hints are welcome. I don't mind coding some JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki.  MozRepl lets you connect via telnet, in combination with netcat this would be exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Is the browser still opened as normal? Like I said I want to make final edits and submit it manually.

Comment: Yes, once you've started firefox normally you are able to telnet into it.

Comment: Thanks. This brought me now to the idea that I can solve this also using a user script, which is simpler (see my own answer). I will accept your answer after a short while.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this now using a Greasemonkey script which copies the URL parameters to the form.
The Makefile calls `firefox` with the URL including the parameters.

This works for my needs. Some refinements would be needed for more complex input, i.e. some URL encoding.

User Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Fill CTAN upload form
// @namespace      http://www.scharrer-online.de/namespace/
// @description    Fills the CTAN upload form with the data provided as URL variables
// @include        http://*.ctan.org/upload.html*
// @require        http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

//var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;

// From http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/
// Added: decodeURI
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = decodeURI(value);
    });
    return vars;
}

var vars = getUrlVars();

for (name in vars) {
    $("input[name=" + name + "]").val(vars[name]);
    $("select[name=" + name + "]").find("option:selected").removeAttr('selected');
    $("select[name=" + name + "]").find("option[value=" + vars[name] + "]")
            .attr('selected','selected');
}

if ('DoNotAnnounce' in vars) {
    var val = vars['DoNotAnnounce'].toLowerCase();
    if (val == '1' || val == 'yes' || val == 'true') {
        $("input[name=DoNotAnnounce]").attr('checked','checked');
    }
}
```

Makefile:

```
# CTAN Upload
CTAN=http://dante.ctan.org/upload.html
CONTRIBUTION=filemod
VERSION=
NAME=John Doe
EMAIL=john.doe@somewhere.com
SUMMARY=Updated to ${VERSION}:
DIRECTORY=/macros/latex/contrib/${CONTRIBUTION}
DONOTANNOUNCE=
ANNOUNCEMENT=
NOTES=
LICENCE=free
FREEVERSION=lppl
#FILE= # can't be set because of security limitations

upload: ctanify
    firefox 'http://dante.ctan.org/upload.html?contribution=${CONTRIBUTION}&version=${VERSION}&name=${NAME}&email=${EMAIL}&summary=${SUMMARY}&directory=${DIRECTORY}&DoNotAnnounce=${DONOTANNOUNCE}&announce=${ANNOUNCEMENT}&notes=${NOTES}&license=${LICENCE}&freeversion=${FREEVERSION}' &
```